# Why is the Java -cp option not working when -jar does while using the spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a simple maven project that creates an executable jar file named `test.jar` in the `target` directory.

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <main.class>com.me.Main</main.class>
    </properties>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

When I run with `java -jar target\test.jar` everything runs fine but when I try to use the `-cp` to run the jar without the `-jar` so I can add things to the classpath like (Windows) `java -cp target\test.jar com.me.Main` I get...

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.me.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.me.Main
```

I also tried other versions like `java -cp "target\test.jar" com.me.Main` but no matter what it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

**Update**

The `MANIFEST.mf` looks like this

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.me.Main
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.2.12.RELEASE
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
```

This seems to show that spring-boot is overriding the Main-Class KV.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, just created an executable jar and I could run it in both ways (Java 11).

Comment: I think the Spring Boot plugin uses the launcher, i.e. it doesn't built a traditional executable jar, but does the weird jar-files-inside-other-jar-files bundling. That means the main class that will be registered there will be a Spring-specific one that just calls your real main (check the manifest of the generated jar to learn the details).

Comment: Generous Badger is correct here, the main class which you would have to use is `org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher`. Check the documentation for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-launching

Comment: @GenerousBadger Looks to be the case. Swapping out the spring boot maven plugin for the assembly plugin seems to be helping the situation. Let me confirm some things.

Comment: @GenerousBadger I will put up an answer and you can improve on it and I will accept yours ok? That way you get credit

Answer (score 1):

If I change to the `maven-assembly-plugin`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    ${main.class}
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

then I can still run as `java -jar` and I can also run with `java -cp`

Answer (score 0):

check the contents of JAR file:

```
jar tvf test.jar
```

should contain a `com/me/Main.class`

and contents of its MANIFEST.MF file:

```
jar xf test.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

and use a text editor to open `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` - should contain line starting with `Main-Class:`  and the fully qualified name of the main class, the one with the `main` method, used when starting the JAR (with `java -jar`)

(or just use WinZIP, 7-zip, or similar to open and check the JAR file)

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @user15793316 Thank you for explaining this response. I would say this is probably not an answer so much as a comment about if I had confirmed these items. Also given the fact that the problem appears to be more related to the Maven Spring plugin when I update the question this answer may not fit. Again, I still really appreciate your help I will post the MANIFEST.MF soon because I am sure the spring one will have some oddities.

Comment: Spring boot builds a special jar. Classes there are not structured as in other jars. As far as I remember, that jar can contain other jars. So the suggestion to look inside jar is actually helpful, even thought, strictly speaking, not an answer

Comment: Well, java handles that jar as a regular jar, but the jar itself is not ordinary. Maven builds the jar and instead of putting mainClass to Main-Class, puts it to Start-Class. The main class is still Spring Boot class, which can launch this special jar. The class specified in maven, is located in BOOT-INF directory inside the jar. And because of that java cant find it, if you put jar in classpath.